# Update JavaFX ListView when List<Object> deviceList has changed

Tags: java, list, listview, javafx

I have a static List in Config Class

```
public class Config {
    public static ObservableList<Device> OnlineDevicesList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
}
```

when the List got changed, i need to change the Items in

```
public class MainViewController {
    @FXML ListView<Device> lvOnlineDevices;
    public void initialize() {
        lvOnlineDevices.getItems().addAll(Config.OnlineDevicesList);
    }
}
```

how can i do that?

Comment: There are better ways to get data to a controller than using `static` see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14190310/2991525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
lvOnlineDevices.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(OnlineDevicesList))
```

But I would suggest to use an ObservableList in your config, then you don't have to convert it evertime you have new items.

Comment: i updated my post, too. You can see that the list is now already an observableArrayList. But its not automatically updating

Comment: I mean using setItems() instead of getItems().addAll()

Comment: Ok, but when a second Item get added, i'll become an exception Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-3

Comment: yes, because you cannot updated the GUI from a non-GUI thread. Either change your code and make sure change the list only in the GUI thread, or wrap  the corresponding command in Platform.runlater(Runnable runnable)